# what other options are there for storing two separate users data without building a server?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

trying to build a simple javascript calculator web app that stores calculations from two different users. I know I can build a simple server for the backend and store data that way, as a single source of truth, but is there a different way?

I believe localStorage only stores data on one user's computer, let me know what you folks think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share info between two different browsers you will have to create a backend (central point).

If the data only matters to each user then you could use localStorage or cookies.

Comment: so i have to create a backend? since im only storing simple calculations, i dont want something too heavy to spin up. do you have any recommendations?

Comment: its a node app currently

Comment: You could just make a basic express server that stores the values in memory (inside variables). Downside is if you restart the server the data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

If you run JavaScript inside a Browser you can only save your data inside that Browser instance. The only way to do what you want to do is build a server to store the data on. The only alternative would be a cloud provider (which technically *is* a server) like Amazon AWS or Microsoft Azure if you don't want to host it yourself.

If the data only matters to each respective user and you don't need any interaction between them, then LocalStorage is perfectly fine as long as it is no sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a riddle. If you don't want to build a server, you can use someone else's server ? :)

There's two ways to go about it. This is kind of showcased in things like iMAP vs POP

1. You have storage on a Server that your clients connect to and retrieve data from. This allows for easy data sharing and scalability.
2. You allow each user to create and alter their own data, storing it on their local system, and then they directly connect with each other over a socket, swap files and save the data from each other. Then you close the connection and open your calculator. Changes are only reported when you actively connect to each other, plus you'd have to write the storage functionality from scratch, and there's no security at all.

Truth is, you should just use a server.